# autofill on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

caveat: I'm pretty new to ajax/js.

I have the following script which works fine:

```
<head>
    <script class="init" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        (function( $ ) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=3429d739de582bfe294836892fb7fc8d&format=1&currencies=GBP,EUR,NOK,ZAR,SEK&format=1",
                    data: {
                        format: 'json'
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log("error");
                    },
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var x=0;
                        for(var key in data.quotes){
                            console.log(x);
                            console.log(data.quotes[key]);
                            document.forms["myForm"].elements[x].value = +(Math.round(1/data.quotes[key] + "e+4")  + "e-4");;
                            x++;
                        }
                    },
                    type: 'GET'
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</head>
```

this automatically fills the form elements with exchange rates.
I now am trying to have it only do this when a button on the page is clicked.
I added:

```
<td>
    <p>
        <input tabindex="8" type="submit" name="submit" id="onlinerates" value="Use Online Rates"/>
    </p>
</td>
```

and then changed the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
$(document.myForm.onlinerates).click(function() {
```

the script now does not appear to get called and the forms are not filled in.

I've tried using document.getElementById("onlinerates") , I've tried preceding this line with an additional  $(document).ready(function() {

I've tried moving the script to within the form instead of the header. I tried using .focus instead of .click

none of that helped.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

### FIXED (sort of):

thanks to Rory for pointing out the issue with the double submit. i changed the onlinerates to use a checkbox instead of submit button. Also, i had to move the script to the form.

```
    <input tabindex="8" type="checkbox" name="onlinerates" id="onlinerates" value=0/><label for="onlinerates">Use Online Rates</label></p>
      
<script class="init" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function( $ ) {
    $('#onlinerates').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission
    if($('#onlinerates').attr("checked")==true){
             $.ajax({url: "http://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=3429d739de582bfe294836892fb7fc8d&format=1&currencies=GBP,EUR,NOK,ZAR,SEK&format=1",
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
       error: function() {
        console.log("error");
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
           var x=0;
            for(var key in data.quotes){
             console.log(x);
             console.log(data.quotes[key]);
             document.forms["myForm"].elements[x].value = +(Math.round(1/data.quotes[key] + "e+4")  + "e-4");;
             x++;
            }
        },
          type: 'GET'
    });
    }
    
    });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `onlinerates` is the `id` of the button, whereas accessing the element through the `form` uses the `name`. That said, it's easier to use jQuery to select the element; `$('#onlinerates')`.

Also note that it's better practice (for accessibility reasons) to hook to the `submit` event of the parent `form` instead of the click of the `button`. Try this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=3429d739de582bfe294836892fb7fc8d&format=1&currencies=GBP,EUR,NOK,ZAR,SEK&format=1",
            type: 'GET'
            data: {
                format: 'json'
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                var x = 0;
                for (var key in data.quotes) {
                    document.forms["myForm"].elements[x].value = +(Math.round(1 / data.quotes[key] + "e+4") + "e-4");
                    x++;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks. using $('#onlinerates'). didn't work. i had tried that already too, and the getElementById("onlinerates") should have covered that anyways. i can't just use submit on the form since there's more than one submit.    is there a way to choose only one of the submits ?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements on your page with that same `id`? Also, note that having multiple submits in a single form is a very bad idea.

Comment: sorry. the form is legacy code. i'd rather not mess with it if i don't have to

Comment: ok. so this is helpful, i moved the script into the form and used the     $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();                         as suggested. this allows it to work if there's only one submit. i'm going to switch the submit for a checkbox and see if that helps.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using an event handler for when the form is submitted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the event handler
    $('#myForm').submit(submitRates);
});

function submitRates(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    // Do AJAX stuff
}
```